# How to create Contour background in android

Tags: java, android

I'm drawing rectangle and filling it with solid color.
i would like also to add contour to the label background.
I want to create something line in outlook when you have a meeting that you didn't respond on.
is it possible?

(I wanted to add a picture, but i don't have enough reputation points)

Thanks,
Gidi

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean something like that?

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#c1001f"/>
    <stroke android:width="6dp" android:color="#000000" />
</shape>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. I can't figure out how to draw this shape on a canvas (currently, my code is drawing Rectangle and I want to replace it with this shape)

Comment: fount the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12821416/draw-rectangle-with-xml-shape-settings-in-android